# Spotlight turns off on and based on distance and angle, even in editor

Tags: unity

I have cloned a spotlight 3 times.  The original and one clone are near eachother and both work as expected.  However, the other two are a few meters away, and behave oddly.  I initially noticed in the player, but it also happens in the editor. If you get a few meters away they go out. I eventually noticed it also happens based on angle, as demonstrated below.

[image]

I am relatively new to Unity, but I've asked the other devs and they are stumped.  **What could cause this?**

Comment: Are you using [Forward rendering](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RenderTech-ForwardRendering.html)? This limits the number of lights that are rendered with full per-pixel fidelity, prioritizing the closest lights.

Comment: I don't think so, but where would I find that setting?  In the example video above, the light in question is *definitely* the closest to the camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of 3 things that might help.

1. Edit->Project Settings->Quality Settings and then set Pixel Light Count to something higher. The default is 2 or 3.
2. Use Deferred rendering mode on your main camera. This is Done by selecting the camera and under the camera componet Rendering Path-> Deferred
3. Set the Render MOde of the light from Auto to Important.

Comment: Option 1 worked like a charm. Is this recommended?  Will it cause issues?

Comment: Just to have an answer to @Devil'sAdvocate's comment above for future readers: this has a cost. Whether that cost is noticeable in your game or causes problems for your use case is something you can only find out through testing and profiling. If you find increasing the pixel light count costs too much in your case, you can instead chop your scene geometry into more chunks, so each chunk only has to be lit by a smaller number of lights, and can neglect more distant lights falling on other chunks.